# custom script for sysv init to systemd conversion

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, systemd, sysvinit

I have a script which is used for performing pre and post health checkup of our RedHat servers and the script is working fine on RHEL 6. Also, i've configured the script in runlevel so that it send me an email before and after reboot. Now I want the same thing to be configured on my RHEL 7 machines, but the problem is when I configured the script in systemd it executes only the post reboot report and not the pre-reboot status. Also when I execute the script manually on my rhel 7 machines it works fine. So i believe there is no problem with my script, there must be some configuration which I'm missing while setting up my custom script to systemd.

Here is my sample systemd config:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript
Description=SYSV: Server Reboot
Before=shutdown.target
After=network.service
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript start
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked something up on a CentOS 7 VM that appears to be working. My *customscript* merely echoes to a file on start, stop, restart, and status (/var/tmp/custom.out). A few minor differences. In the "[Unit]" stanza you have "After=network.service", I have "After=network-online.target" and "After=remote-fs.target". I also added "Wants=network-online.target". Another difference is I changed "Type=forking" to "Type=simple" in the "[Service]" stanza since I'm assuming the script isn't a dameon meant to run in the background.

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript
Description=LSB: Start daemon at boot time
Before=shutdown.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=network-online.target
After=postfix.service
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript start
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For reference, my /etc/rc.d/init.d/customscript file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          customscript
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

# Using the lsb functions to perform the operations.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Custom Start at $(date)" >> /var/tmp/custom.out
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Custom Stop at $(date)" >> /var/tmp/custom.out
        ;;
    restart)
        echo "Custom Restart at $(date)" >> /var/tmp/custom.out
        ;;
    status)
        echo "Custom Status at $(date)" >> /var/tmp/custom.out
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Custom other at $(date)" >> /var/tmp/custom.out
        ;;
esac
```

Here is /var/tmp/custom.out. I shutdown at 13:04, waited a few minutes and booted. After another 20 minutes executed another shutdown, waited a little more than another 2 minutes and booted again.

```
Custom Stop at Thu Jun  1 13:04:37 PDT 2017
Custom Start at Thu Jun  1 13:10:39 PDT 2017
Custom Stop at Thu Jun  1 13:30:07 PDT 2017
Custom Start at Thu Jun  1 13:32:45 PDT 2017
```

However, I'm wondering if your issue could also be that the script hasn't completed by the time the system shuts down?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but my script should work like a daemon. My script just collects the system info like cpu, memory, disk, network, grub etc., before and after reboot and it should send me an email with all the details. But now I'm getting only the post reboot report via email. Even I also thought the same thing what you have said, my server reboots before the script complete. So my question is what parameter should I adjust/configure on my custom script systemd file to make my server to wait till the script completes.

Comment: First change I would make is setting `Type=simple` and `After=network-online.target`.

Comment: Hi @Deathgrip, I've tried your script with some modification. After the case statement echo out the value to a file, I just added another line to send the output via email. like this:
cat /var/tmp/custom.out | mail -s "Stop Status" root@localhost
Like that, I've created an additional line for all 4 case statements, but now the problem is the script send the output via email only during startup and not at shutdown. Any clue?

I've created the systemd file as same as you posted here above.

Comment: But on shutdown `/var/tmp/custom.out` is being written to? Change `[Service]` `Type=oneshot` and try.

Comment: Also add `After=postfix.service` to the service definition. You may want to add a small sleep to the end of the init.d script to allow Postfix to process the email completely. Have you looked in /var/log/maillog for evidence of possibly interrupted email transfers? We may need to move this to a chat room if there's much more q & a.

Comment: Thanks, @Deathgrip. I've updated my systemd file as you said and updated my script to sleep for 10 sec at the end of case statement which helped in fixing the problem I had. Now I get the email before and after reboot. Thanks again.